# Keep the token active by updating its expiration date to not receive the error Token has been expired or revoke

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Based on [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python?hl=pt-br) I tried to use this code to keep my token active:

```python
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                "client_secrets.json", SCOPES
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

But to my surprise (my poor knowledge made me understand that everything was ok), even though the code was executed every half hour every day without interruption, today my token lost its validity and I had to delete the `token.json` file. for a new token to be created.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Squads Python\squads_sw.py", line 796, in <module>
    download_file("109fDhTJNR2iHeA4bgcHTcWtZZ2dShKR-", file_base_name)
  File "c:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Squads Python\squads_sw.py", line 429, in download_file
    creds.refresh(Request())
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", line 335, in refresh
    ) = reauth.refresh_grant(
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\reauth.py", line 351, in refresh_grant
    _client._handle_error_response(response_data, retryable_error)
  File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 73, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

What is the error with the code that does not keep the token updated so that it is not necessary to authorize it again every X days?

Comment: You can get a refresh token to extend access, but even refresh tokens typically expire. This seems to be a good explanation : https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-refresh/

Comment: Hi @JonSG therefore, there is no way to put code to run in the cloud because at some point it will be necessary to manually approve it again in the browser?

Comment: Usually there is a way to programmatically get a new based token. I seem to recall I wrote code to do that for an oauth authenticated service. I'll see if I can drudge it up.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens for apps in testing expire after seven days

Go to the credentials tab for your project and set it to production it will stop expiring